# Query number of resources in a Qt Resource Collection (.qrc)

Tags: c++, qt, resources, qt5

I am compiling multiple Qt Linguist Message files (.qm) into a Qt Resource Collection file (.qrc). That `translatons.qrc` file is compiled into the application via `rcc`, so that I can access the resources via `":/translations/<locale_name>.qm"`.

Is there a way to query the number of resources for a specific prefix?

In my case, when I add two .qm files into the .qrc file I would like to programmatically obtain the result `2`. The class [QResource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qresource.html) does not seem to fulfill such a request, since it only seems to work with resources directly. I am using Qt v5.4.

Comment: Did you try `QDir( ":/translations" ).entryList().size()` ?

Comment: or even QDir( ":/translations" ).count() http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qdir.html#count

Comment: Captain Obvious strikes again. Resources can be handled like file paths... @SaZ: If u make an answer out of your comment I will happily upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may work with resource system in same manner, as file system, for example:

`QDir( ":/translations" ).entryList()`